# Comparing two lists with MSpec

Tags: c#, tdd, bdd, mspec

Which method should I use to assert that two lists contains the same objects with MSpec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `ShouldContainOnly(IEnumerable<T>)` extension method.

So if you have 2 lists, `listA` and `listB` use:

```
listA.ShouldContainOnly(listB)
```

Comment: ...but check that your objects implement `Equals` appropriately. Machine.Specifications looks for `IComparable<T>`, `IComparable`, `IEquatable<T>`, and then uses `Comparer<T>.Default`.

Comment: will that include order of the items check?

Answer (score 4):

If the order of the items in the list doesn't matter, you would use

```
listA.ShouldContainOnly(listB); // both lists must have exactly the same items
listA.ShouldContain(listB);     // listA must at least contain the items of listB
```

If the order of the items matters, you can use

```
listA.ShouldEqual(listB);
```